# Photoshop COM and C++ (How to)

Tags: c++, com, photoshop

I would like to use Photoshop via COM using C++, but I'm not sure if I'm getting it right. I've seen lot's of tutorials on how to do that with C# and even tried one but as far as I know ideology of COM says that you can use any language you like since it's source is just binary. So, C++ is exactly what I want and to start I should have a photoshop interface class in my client programm, right ? So, the question is: Where can I get it (interface class) ? And even if I had one, how would I know about functions to operate photoshop instance. Or maybe I understanding COM + C++ wrong ? Your help is highly appreciate.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your question is very general... go to adobe.com and get the photoshop sdk - it comes with lots of documetnation, samples etc. Then you check with your C++ environment on how to interface with COM (for example via ATL)... when you have done all that and get stuck then you come back to SO with specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Photoshop SDK can be used for creating panels and plugins, right ? What I would like to do is a bit different. I want another programm to open Photoshop instance and make N operations. So, in sdk I've found nothing about COM Interface, which I should declare in my client programm to operate with PhotoshopCOM. Yeah, probably I'm not very specific, but I can't find a point to start. As I beleive, that point is Photoshop COM Interface class.

Comment: the photoshop SDK can be used for both - plugin/panels AND for COM... it contains among other things documentation for COM interfaces of Photoshop AND samples!

Comment: Yahia, thanks a lot! OLE Automation ... silly me, were doing "search text: 'COM'". Once again, thanks a lot. I owe you beer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, COM is language-neutral, but it requires a lot of extra runtime work to ask the OS for pointers to the interfaces and methods you need.  COM is a huge pain in C++.  You're looking at 5-10 lines of code for a single function call.  Microsoft's "helper" libraries like MFC and ATL can help make it easier, but it's still not pretty.

C# abstracts a lot of the details away and makes COM look like regular object-oriented code.  In C++, you'd have to write the wrapper class yourself or find someone else's implementation.  It won't necessarily be hard, but it will be tedious.

I work with COM in C++ and I would jump at the chance to do it with C# instead.

Comment: Thanks you for you comment. Indeed, with C# it took not much time to connect to PS and was obviously easier. The reason why I want to do that in C++ is, I already got a c++ tool which now should operate photoshope instance.